# ERROR 4: Unable to open EPSG support file gcs.csv

Tags: qgis, python, pyqgis, standalone

I am writing a standalone QGIS python application to run some unittests. I am getting an error when I try to use the `QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem` library.

```
ERROR 4: Unable to open EPSG support file gcs.csv. Try setting the GDAL_DATA 
environment variable to point to the directory containing EPSG csv files.
```

I am running QGIS 3.0.3 on Windows 7.

I have made sure my `GDAL_DATA` path points to the gdal folder containing the `gcs.csv`. I have even placed a print statement above and below the call to `QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem` to print the environment variable which is correct as `C:\Program Files\QGIS 3.0\share\gdal`.

Any insight into this would be most helpful.

my full code is:

```
import os
from qgis.core import QgsApplication, QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem

app = QgsApplication([], True)
app.setPrefixPath(r"C:\Program Files\QGIS 3.0\apps\qgis", True)
app.initQgis()

app.setPluginPath(app.pluginPath().replace("\n", ""))
app.setPkgDataPath(app.pkgDataPath().replace("\n", ""))

print(os.environ["GDAL_DATA"])
c = QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem(4326)
print(os.environ["GDAL_DATA"])
```

This Python script is called from the following batch file:

```
@ECHO OFF

call "C:\Program Files\QGIS 3.0\bin\o4w_env.bat"
call "C:\Program Files\QGIS 3.0\bin\qt5_env.bat"
call "C:\Program Files\QGIS 3.0\bin\py3_env.bat"

set PYTHONPATH=%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\apps\qgis\python;%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\apps\qgis\python\plugins;%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Roaming\QGIS\QGIS3\profiles\default\python\plugins%PYTHONPATH%

python test.py
```

Comment: What about GEOTIFF_CSV="C:\Program Files\QGIS 3.0\share\gdal"? There is more than one GDAL system variable...where/how have you set the GDAL_DATA path? What gets printed by print(os.environ["GDAL_DATA"])? In older versions of GDAL the space in the path was a definite no-no but I think that has been fixed now.

Comment: GEOTIFF_CSV is set to ``C:\Program Files\QGIS3.0\share\gdal\epsg_csv``.
The GDAL_DATA variable is set when running ``o4w_env.bat``. My qgis-bin.exe works fine, no problems, it is only when i run it as a standalone application that it has a problem, so i believe my gdal installation is fine.

Comment: And PROJ_LIB? That should then be C:\Program Files\QGIS3.0\share\gdal\proj. Are these being overwritten somehow... try for Env in ['GDAL_DATA' ,'GDAL_DRIVER_PATH','GEOTIFF_CSV','PROJ_LIB']: print ('{} : {}'.format(Env,os.environ.get(Env))) early in the program to check the values haven't been corrupted.

Comment: All the paths look good before an after. However it seems after running ``app.initQgis()`` all the paths are appended with a line break (``\n``). By forcefully setting ``os.environ["GDAL_DATA"] = os.environ["GDAL_PATH"].replace("\n", "")`` it removes the error.  I dont know why ``initQgis()`` is adding line breaks.

Comment: Thanks for you help, I did not notice the line breaks until I printed out all the variables in your loop.

Comment: That sounds like an answer to me, can you post your updated code as an answer to your own question for future users with the same problem.

Answer (score 5):

My `GDAL_DATA` environment variable was wrong, it had a line break (`\n`) at the end causing my error. I fixed it by forcefully changing the environment variable to remove the line break.

`QgsApplication.instance().initQgis()` appears to add line breaks to the end of all my environment paths. I have patched this by replacing the line break in each variable manually.

Please see complete code below:

```
import os
from qgis.core import QgsApplication, QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem

app = QgsApplication([], True)
app.setPrefixPath(r"C:\Program Files\QGIS 3.0\apps\qgis", True)
app.initQgis()

app.setPluginPath(app.pluginPath().replace("\n", ""))
app.setPkgDataPath(app.pkgDataPath().replace("\n", ""))

# With line break at the end
print(os.environ["GDAL_DATA"])

os.environ["GDAL_DATA"] = os.environ["GDAL_DATA"].replace("\n", "")
# Without line break
print(os.environ["GDAL_DATA"])

c = QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem(4326)
```

**EDIT 6/6/2018**
I found the problem to occur when after `import qgis`, this call seems to change the system variables. I have solved this by copying the environment variables before importing and then replacing them after.

```
import os

environment_variables = os.environ.copy()
import qgis
os.environ = environment_variables

from qgis.core import QgsApplication, QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem

app = QgsApplication([], True)
app.setPrefixPath(r"C:\Program Files\QGIS 3.0\apps\qgis", True)
app.initQgis()

c = QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem(4326)
```

Comment: That's great, I'm sure there will be many to come with the same problem.