# Using rasterio.crs module

Tags: python, gdal, rasterio

I try to project a raster into another projection and I cannot manage to use the `rasterio.crs` module

I can obtain the CRS of a file using the following code :

```py
import rasterio as rio

with rio.open('a_file.tif') as f: # not relevant that I give you the file
    print(f.crs)
crs
>>> CRS.from_epsg(4326)
```

If instead I want to create a CRS from scratch with :

```py
rio.crs.CRS.from_string('EPSG:4326')
```

I get the following error :

> CPLE_OpenFailedError: Unable to open EPSG support file gcs.csv.  Try setting the GDAL_DATA environment variable to point to the directory containing EPSG csv files.

So I checked the `GDAL_DATA`env variable :

```py
import os 

os.environ['GDAL_DATA']
>>> '/usr/share/gdal'
```

but no trace of a gcs.csv file.

### Note

- I work in a shared environment and I cannot afford to just rebuild everything from scratch.
- The gdal CLI is also installed in this environment and looking at the documentation I think they are not compatible.
- I tried to start my file by

```
import os 

if 'GDAL_DATA' in list(os.environ.keys()): del os.environ['GDAL_DATA']
if 'PROJ_LIB' in list(os.environ.keys()): del os.environ['PROJ_LIB']
```

but it doesn't change anything

### Questions

How can I use the rasterio.crs module?
Where should be pointing the GDAL_DATA?
Is it a real error or just hiding something else?

### config

```
Python==3.6.9
rasterio==1.1.8
pyproj==2.6.1
GDAL==3.0.4
```

Comment: Can you please provide the version of the tools you use, especially Python, PROJ, GDAL and rasterio?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a known issue of rasterio (in conda for example)

Answers are given in

- [Where is “ERROR 4: Unable to open EPSG support file gcs.csv” coming from and what does it mean?](https://rasterio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq.html)
- [How to set the GDAL_DATA environment variable to point to the directory containing EPSG csv files?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14465201)
- [ERROR 4: Unable to open EPSG support file gcs.csv](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/284709/error-4-unable-to-open-epsg-support-file-gcs-csv)
- [Unable to open EPSG support file gcs.csv #1539](https://github.com/mapbox/rasterio/issues/1539)
- [Missing gcs.csv file](https://inbo.github.io/niche_vlaanderen/faq.html#missing-gcs-csv-file)

and many more.

Try setting the GDAL_DATA environment to a path which contains a gcs.csv file (use search to find a path)

```
os.environ['GDAL_DATA'] = '.../site-packages/rasterio/gdal_data'
```

Or

```
os.environ['GDAL_DATA'] = '..../site-packages/fiona/gdal_data'
```

Comment: sorry for the duplicate and thank you for taking the time to anwser